# webmethod not call on firebase notification onMessageReceived method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    try {

        String type=remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
        if(type.equals("1001")) {
            CommonClass common = new CommonClass(getApplication());
            CommonClass.MyTaskSendLog.execute(getApplicationContext(), DeviceDetails,lines);
        }            
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

this code gives error:

> Method execute must be called from the main thread, currently inferred
>   thread is worker

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue with AsyncTask, but bizarrely it doesn't show the error if the call to execute is simply inside another method (called from onMessageReceived). Surely this must be the same thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your method is in a service.

To access UI thread (main thread) in a service you have to create an handler and call method inside as this:

```
if(type.equals("1001")) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                          CommonClass common = new CommonClass(getApplication());
                          CommonClass.MyTaskSendLog.execute(getApplicationContext(), DeviceDetails,lines);
                  }
    });
}
```

You could create Handler in `onCreate` of service.

Comment: How to call that handler on onMessageReceived() method.

Comment: Replace your code inside if(type.equals("1001")) { ...} by my code